# Can I keep stored data for a Greasemonkey script even when it's uninstalled?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I've written a Greasemonkey script that saves preferences using `GM_SetValue`.  Sometimes, if there's an issue with the script, I advise users to reload the script by removing it and re-installing.  This blows away the stored values for the script, which is very inconvenient for the user.

Is there a better way to store this information?  The state I need to store is per-page, using the URL as a key for `GM_SetValue`, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can copy the SQLite file that stores `GM_setValue` data and preserve that information.

To find the data:

1. Go to your [Firefox profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox).
2. Enter the `gm_scripts` folder therein.
3. The appropriate file will be named based on the script name and will have the extension `.db`.
   For example if the script is named:
   `// @name  _Zombie GM_setValue fun`
   Then the SQLite file will be named:
   `_Zombie_GM_setValue_fun.db`

If you move or copy this file to a safe place, then do whatever to the script, then copy the file back; your data will be preserved. (As long as you don't change the script's `@name` or `@namespace`.)
You don't have to close Firefox while you do this, but I would -- to guard against edge-case mishaps.

**Example script:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Zombie GM_setValue fun
// @include  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498610/*
// @grant    GM_getValue
// @grant    GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

var lastVal = GM_getValue ("LastValue");
var newVal  = prompt (
    'The last value was "' + (lastVal || "{not set}") + '". Enter a new value:',
    ''
);
if (newVal)
    GM_setValue ("LastValue", newVal);
```

Test sequence:

1. Install the script.
2. Reload this very page ([stackoverflow.com/questions/28498610/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498610/)).
3. You'll see `The last value was "{not set}". Enter a new value:`.
4. Enter `Save me`.
5. Reload the page.
6. You'll see `The last value was "Save me". Enter a new value:`
7. Copy `_Zombie_GM_setValue_fun.db` to a safe place.
8. Uninstall the script and (optionally) restart Firefox.
9. Reinstall the script.
10. Load the page and you'll see `"{not set}"` as in step 3.
11. Copy the saved `_Zombie_GM_setValue_fun.db` back to the `gm_scripts` folder, overwriting the newer `_Zombie_GM_setValue_fun.db` if it is present.
12. Reload the page you'll see `Save me` as in step 6.

Comment: I was kind of hoping for something a little easier on the end user, some of whom are not technically inclined.  One solution I've been exploring is to switch to `localStorage` -- I think my user base should all be on a modern-enough browser version to have at least basic support, and the data I'm storing isn't sensitive.  As far as I can tell, that persists through script uninstalls. Can you think of any downsides?

Comment: `localStorage` often works good enough. The only downsides are that it's not cross-domain, and that some websites (Like Facebook IIRC) will trash it on you.